# Unable to understand the functioning of the python code

Tags: python, loops, indentation

```
def dtb(num):
    if num > 1:
        dtb(num//2)
    print(num%2,end='')

dtb(10)
```

I understand the recursion part but not able to understand the rest code.Can someone please provide a step by step explanation.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you not understand? The syntax error caused by `def(10)`? The division `num//2`, the modulo operator `%`, the arguments of `print`?

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  Stack Overflow is not a personalized tutorial resource.  We expect you to make a good attempt to understand this on your own first, including tracing the execution by hand and/or `print` statements.  When you have a *specific* question -- not "explain this program to me in detail", *then* you will have something good to post here.

Comment: Also check [can someone help me?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Comment: What is happening in between dtb(num//2) and print(num%2,end='').

Answer (score 1):

This function converts an integer decimal number to a binary number.

// - operator of floor division. For example (13//5) will return 2

PS. You need to write dtb(10) instead of def(10) to call tour method.

Answer (score 0):

If it's the print part thats confusing you, it will print num mod 2 (the remainder after dividing by 2). The end='' is so python doesn't print a new line after, which it does by default.

As for the def(10), I'm assuming thats a typo. It should be dtb(10) which would call the recursive function on the integer 10.